# Hello World using x86 assembler on Mac 0SX

Tags: macos, linker, x86, assembly

I am trying to dive into some x86 assembly programming on my Mac, but am having trouble producing an executable.  The problem seems to be at the linking stage.

helloWorld.s:

```
.data

    HelloWorldString:
    .ascii "Hello World\n"

.text

.globl _start

_start:
    # load all the arguments for write()
    movl $4, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $HelloWorldString, %ecx
    movl $12, %edx
    # raises software interrupt to call write()
    int $0x80

    # call exit()
    movl $1, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

Assemble the program:

```
as -o helloWorld.o helloWorld.s
```

Link the object file:

```
ld -o helloWorld helloWorld.o
```

The error I get at this point is:

```
ld: could not find entry point "start" (perhaps missing crt1.o) for inferred architecture x86_64
```

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong / missing would be very helpful. thanks

Comment: I know I'm a bit late, but you need to change `_start` to `start`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You'll probably find it easier to build with gcc rather than trying to micro-manage the assembler and linker, e.g.

```
$ gcc helloWorld.s -o helloWorld
```

(You'll probably want to change `_start` to `_main` if you go this route.)

Incidentally, it can be instructive to start with a working C program, and study the generated asm from this. E.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    puts("Hello world!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

when compiled with `gcc -Wall -O3 -m32 -fno-PIC hello.c -S -o hello.S` generates:

```
    .cstring
LC0:
    .ascii "Hello world!\12\0"
    .text
    .align 4,0x90
.globl _main
_main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $24, %esp
    movl    $LC0, (%esp)
    call    _puts
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    leave
    ret
    .subsections_via_symbols
```

You might want to consider using this as a template for your own "Hello world" or other experimental asm programs, especially given that it already builds and runs:

```
$ gcc -m32 hello.S -o hello
$ ./hello 
Hello world!
```

One final comment: beware of taking examples from Linux-oriented asm books or tutorials and trying to apply them under OS X - there are important differences !

Comment: Any idea why I'd get this error while doing `gcc -m32 hello.S -o hello`? ld: warning: PIE disabled. Absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) not allowed in code signed PIE, but used in _main from /var/folders/9b/n3lsk87513d57pzh0qvxjmz00000gn/T/hello-r4fQK2.o. To fix this warning, don't compile with -mdynamic-no-pic or link with -Wl,-no_pie

Comment: Are you using an unusual platform ?

Comment: @michaelsnowden the code was generated with -fno-PIC, so if you want to compile it you need to use `gcc -m32 -Wl,-no_pie hello.S -o hello`. Alternatively, generate the code without `-fno-PIC`. That will give you slightly more complex boilerplate, but then you can compile it without having to deal with the PIE issue.

Comment: 2023 update: `i386` architecture is deprecated and no longer supported. Instead of the `-m32` parameter, you should use `-m64`. Surprisingly, after so many years, just these two small changes are needed to compile and link the code above.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
ld -e _start -arch x86_64 -o HelloWorld HelloWorld.S
```

then:

```
./HelloWorld
```

Info:

```
-e <entry point>
-arch <architecture>, You can check your architecture by uname -a 
-o <output file>
```

Comment: Yes that will assemble+link, but the code in the question is *not* for x86-64 MacOS.  It's for i386 Linux.  After fixing that (see NoOffenceIntended's answer), then this answer will work.  You can leave out the `-e _start` part if you give your entry point the standard (for MacOS) label of `start:` instead of `_start:`

Answer (score 2):

## hello.asm

```
.data

    HelloWorldString:
    .ascii "Hello World!\n"

.text

.globl start

start:
    ; load all the arguments for write()
    movl $0x2000004, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    movq HelloWorldString@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rsi
    movq $100, %rdx
    ; raises software interrupt to call write()
    syscall

    ; call exit()
    movl $0x2000001, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx
    syscall
```

## Then run:

```
$ as -arch x86_64  -o hello.o hello.asm
$ ld -o hello hello.o
$ ./hello
```

This is a working solution for Mac OS X Mach-0 GNU-based assemblers

Comment: This worked for me but had to remove the commented code in .asm file.
Also passing in `-macosx_version_min 10.6` to linker command avoids warning, though it compiles anyway.

Comment: Printing 100 bytes when your string is shorter will include a bunch of garbage in the output.  Probably all `0` bytes which don't have any effect on a terminal so you didn't fix this bug.  Also, `exit()` takes its arg from EDI, not EBX.  Maybe you're thinking of the 32-bit Linux int 0x80 ABI?  Oh, that was copied from the question.  Also there's no need to fetch a pointer from memory (from the GOT) for access to your own static data.  Just calculate it directly with a RIP-relative LEA like @NoOffenceIntended's answer.

Comment: Also, `;` is not the comment character for `as` for x86-64.  It separate statements / instructions on the same line, so the assembler will try to parse your comments as code.  If you tested this at all, I assume it was before adding comments.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question looks like it's for 32-bit Linux using the `int $0x80` ABI with args in EBX, ECX, EDX.

x86-64 code on MacOS uses the `syscall` instruction, with arg-passing and return value *similar* to what's documented in the x86-64 System V ABI for Linux.  It's completely different from `int $0x80`, the only similarity being that the call number is passed in EAX/RAX.  But the call numbers are different: https://sigsegv.pl/osx-bsd-syscalls/ ORed with `0x2000000`.

Args go in the same registers as for function calls. (except R10 instead of RCX.)

See also [basic assembly not working on Mac (x86_64+Lion)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179400/basic-assembly-not-working-on-mac-x86-64lion) and [How to get this simple assembly to run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34190930/how-to-get-this-simple-assembly-to-run/34191324#34191324)

---

I think this is a lot neater and more intuitive version of what was suggested in another answer.

OS X uses `start`, not `_start`, for the process entry point.

```
.data
str:
  .ascii "Hello world!\n"
  len = . - str                  # length = start - end.   . = current position

.text
.globl start
start:
    movl   $0x2000004, %eax
    movl   $1, %edi
    leaq   str(%rip), %rsi  
    movq   $len, %rdx          
    syscall                       # write(1, str, len)

    movl   $0x2000001, %eax 
    movl   $0, %edi
    syscall                       # _exit(0)
```

Normally you'd omit the operand-size suffix when a register implies it.  And use `xor %edi,%edi` to zero RDI.

And use `mov $len, %edx` because you know the size is smaller than 4GB so a more efficient 32-bit zero-extended mov-immediate will work, like you're doing to set RAX to the call number.

Notice the use of a RIP-relative LEA to get the address of static data into a register.  x86-64 code on MacOS can't use 32-bit absolute addressing because the base address where your executable will be mapped is above 2^32.

There are no relocation types for 32-bit absolute addresses so you can't use them.  (And you want RIP-relative, not 64-bit absolute, even though that's also supported.)

Comment: Yes, this code is better.  It still had one bug which I fixed, now I think it's a good example.  I also added some explanatory text.  I didn't fix the inefficiencies of wasted code-size (I left the operand-sizes matching the documented system call arg widths, instead of using implicit zero-extension).  And I didn't put the read-only string data into a read-only-data section.  (Like `.rodata` on Linux, IDK what OS X calls it.)

Answer (score 0):

To assemble and link the code in [@NoOffenceIntended's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288921/hello-world-using-x86-assembler-on-mac-0sx/56945021#56945021) on MacOS 10.15, the following changes need to be made:

Change `.global _start` to `.global main`, and `_start:` to `main:`

To assemble and link the code use:

```
as -arch x86_64 -o hello.o hello.asm
ld -arch x86_64 -o hello hello.o -lSystem
```

This is assuming that "Apple clang version 12.0.0" of "as" is being used and the corresponding "ld" is used.

Comment: Which "above code" are you talking about?  There are multiple other answers with code, if you meant one of those, include a link to it (and maybe mention the author's name). Or if you mean the code in the question, it uses 32-bit Linux `int $0x80` system calls with args in registers per the Linux 32-bit ABI; MacOS/Darwin puts args for `int $0x80` on the stack.  But IIRC, 10.15 doesn't support 32-bit code at all, so I doubt you're talking about the question.

Comment: Sorry about that.  The code I was referring to was posted by @NoOffenceIntended on 7/9/19 at 3:39 and posted / edited by Peter Cordes on7/9/19 at 4:24. (I'm not sure how to link directly to that code example.)

Comment: Every answer has a "share" link under it, which you can use to get a link directly to it.  I edited this to add the link.