# GNU Assembly Issues on OSX - Referencing Strings

Tags: macos, assembly, gnu

I've run into an issue after following this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvvRO_gWYIg

A few possible issues:

- it looks like the processor architecture and operating system may differ quite heavily from the one I'm working on.  In the video it seems to be an i386 linux box, and I'm working on an x64 OSX machine.
- When commenting out the helloWorldStr reference, it starts working again.
- Assembling on a 64 bit machine with 32 bit instructions

Posted below is the broken code, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
# Hello World Program:

.data
  HelloWorldStr:
    .ascii "Hello World"

.text
  .globl start

  start:
    # Load all the arguments for write():
    # write(output, string, string_size)
    movl $4, %eax  # Load write()
    movl $1, %ebx  # Arg Output of write() :: STDOUT
    movl $HelloWorldStr, %ecx  # Referencing the Memory Loc. of the String
    movl $11, %edx  # Byte length of the String "Hello World"
    int $0x80

    # Call Exit:
    movl $1, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

Also, here are some errors that have arisen:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So I changed _start to _main and then that passed on to the next error:

```
gcc HelloWorldProgram.s -m32
ld: warning: PIE disabled. Absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) not allowed in code signed PIE, but used in _main from /var/folders/8t/7639_vls58lgd1nnwx4dpbh40000gn/T//cc3wDW8K.o. To fix this warning, don't compile with -mdynamic-no-pic or link with -Wl,-no_pie
```

Answer (score 0):

You might check out [this answer from a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4289132/2167797). The user was also using Mac OS X and following a similar tutorial that was taught using Linux.

Here's an example hello world generated with a slightly newer compiler than the linked to answer (it's still quite similar).

**hello.s**

```
    .section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
L_.str:
    .asciz   "Hello world!\n"

    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .globl  _main
    .align  4, 0x90
_main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $8, %esp
    movl    $L_.str, (%esp)
    call    _puts
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addl    $8, %esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret

.subsections_via_symbols
```