# How to get this simple assembly to run?

Tags: macos, assembly, linker, x86-64, nasm

This is my first ever attempt at programming with assembly.  I'm using a 64 bit Mac OS.  I'm also using NASM.  I've done a lot of looking around for a solution, but I can't find anything that works for my machine.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?  Here is the code and error, thanks!

**hello.asm**

```
    global start

    section .text
start:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, message
    mov rdx, 13
    syscall
    mov eax, 60
    xor rdi, rdi
    syscall
message:
    db "Hello, World", 10
```

**my attempt at executing:**

```
nasm -f macho64 hello.asm -o hello.o
ld -arch i386 -o hello hello.o
./hello
```

**the error**

```
ld: warning: -macosx_version_min not specified, assuming 10.10
ld: warning: ignoring file hello.o, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xCF 0xFA 0xED 0xFE 0x07 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386): hello.o
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

Comment: If you are targeting 64-bit code (executable), which clearly you are doing, remove `-arch i386` from your _LD_ command line.

Comment: @MichaelPetch That worked, thanks!  However, now I'm getting a `Segmentation fault 11`.  Any idea how I can fix this?  Thanks.

Comment: Your code is for linux but you are apparently on macos.

Comment: You seem to be using Linux syscalls on OS/X. The write syscall on OS/X in 64-bit code is 0x20000004 and exit syscall is 0x20000001 . In 32-bit code on OS/X you subtract 0x20000000 off each syscall (so they are 4 and 1 in 32-bit).

Comment: Wow, I'm unbelievably confused.  Thanks for solving my problem, though.  If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for your linker error is that you created a 64-bit macho object using *NASM*, but then targeted i386 for the executable. What you likely were after was a 64-bit executable, which could be done by removing `-arch` like this:

```
ld -o hello hello.o
```

As for your segfault when running your program, it seems that you likely followed a tutorial that may have been designed for Linux. OS/X isn't base upon Linux, it derived from BSD so the Syscalls are different. We could tell you were using Linux Syscalls because *syscall* 1 is *sys_write* and *sys_exit* is rax = 60. This unfortunately isn't the same for OS/X. In 64-bit OS/X code *sys_exit* is rax=0x20000001  and *sys_write* is rax=0x20000004 .

Your code would have to be changed to:

```
    global start

    section .data
message: db "Hello, World", 10  

    section .text
start:
    mov rax, 0x20000004
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, message
    mov rdx, 13
    syscall
    mov rax, 0x20000001
    xor rdi, rdi
    syscall
```

You'll also observe I explicitly declared a `.data` section and placed your variable in it. In some environments it may cause problems if data variables are placed in the code.

If creating 32-bit code on OS/X (you aren't in this case) the Syscalls have 0x20000000 subtracted from each. So in 32-bit OS/X code *sys_exit* is eax=0x1  and *sys_write* is eax=0x4 .

A reference for all the Syscalls (and their parameters) on OS/X can be found in this [Apple information](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1504.3.12/bsd/kern/syscalls.master). Just add 0x20000000 to each number in the first column of the chart for 64-bit assembler code.

You probably want to find a 64-bit OS/X tutorial about Syscalls. This is a [simple one](https://filippo.io/making-system-calls-from-assembly-in-mac-os-x/)