# How to create a socket on Apple Silicon (aarch64 macos) assembly

Tags: macos, sockets, assembly, arm64, apple-silicon

I'm trying to create a socket using `aarch64` assembly on a Apple Silicon device, here's what I have so far.

```
.equ SYS_write, 4
.equ SYS_exit, 0x80
.equ SYS_socket, 196

SOCK_ID:  .byte 0

.text
.global _main
.align 8            // Make sure everything is aligned properly

_main:
    // write(1, msg, msg_len);
    MOV x0, #1              // 1 = StdOut
    ADR x1, msg             // string to print
    MOV x2, msg_len         // length of our string
    BL write                // Call the write function

    // socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);
    BL socket               // Call the socket function
    ADR x3, SOCK_ID
    STR x0, [x3]

    BL _exit                // Exit program

socket:
    MOV x0, PF_INET6
    MOV x1, SOCK_STREAM
    MOV x2, protocol
    MOV x16, SYS_socket     // Unix socket system call
    SVC #0                  // Call kernel to create a socket
    RET

write:
    MOV x16, SYS_write      // Unix write system call
    SVC #0                  // Call kernel to output the string
    RET

_exit:
    MOV x0, #0x00           // Use 0 return code
    MOV x16, #0x01          // System call number 1 terminates this program
    SVC SYS_exit            // Call kernel to terminate the program


// Misc Variables
msg:    .asciz "Starting Program!\n"
msg_len = (. - msg)

// Socket Variables
PF_INET6 = 30
SOCK_STREAM = 1
protocol = 1
```

Essentially, I want to store the value of the socket id saved in `x0` after executing the system call into another register or label. In this case `SOCK_ID` is the label where I want to store the socket id.

However, when I run this I'm getting a `Bus error: 10`.

I'm using a Makefile to assemble and run the file, here's what my Makefile looks like

```make
.PHONY: all

all: main

run:
    ./file

main: file.o
    ld -o file file.o \
        -lSystem \
        -syslibroot `xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-path` \
        -arch arm64 

file.o: file.s
    as -arch arm64 -o file.o file.s
```

Comment: Where did you find the system call numbers?

Comment: There's some info at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48845697/macos-64-bit-system-call-table though I am not completely sure how much carries over to arm64.  One note is that Apple doesn't really want you to issue system calls directly, and doesn't necessarily promise forward compatibility for that interface.  The preferred method is to just call `socket` in the standard C library; is there a reason you can't or don't want to do that?

Comment: But in particular, the system call numbers from those links don't match yours.

Comment: @NateEldredge I updated the syscall numbers to `.equ SYS_write 4`, `.equ SYS_exit, 1` and `.equ SYS_socket, 97` but I'm still getting a Bus Error

Comment: You allocated 1 byte for `SOCK_ID` and stored 8 bytes there?  And the actual returned value is 4 bytes (I'm not sure if it's guaranteed to be sign-extended).

Comment: Oh, and you didn't put `SOCK_ID` in the `.data` section. So it may have gone into `.text` which is not writable.

Comment: There's also a note on that page about needing to have one of the high bits set in the system call number.  I don't recall if that applies to arm64 but it might.

Comment: The high bit thing only applies to x86_64. But the `.data` vs `.text` thing is likely the cause of the bus error.

Comment: I considered that as well, upon placing it in a `.data` section I end up getting `todo.s:13:2: error: unknown AArch64 fixup kind! ADR x1, msg`