# Using the brk system call on macOS, Yasm

Tags: macos, x86, nasm, x86-64, yasm

I've been trying to find a way to use the `brk` system call in a Yasm program on macOS. I've looked in the `syscall.inc` file for that system call, but I couldn't find it there.
Is there any alternative to `brk` on macOS?

Comment: `69 NONE NONE ALL { int sbrk(int incr); } ` in x86-64 you need to add 0x20000000 to the system call number so it would be (0x20000000)+69. System call numbers can be found here:  https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-792.13.8/bsd/kern/syscalls.master

Comment: Here is an example of MacOS system calls (plus additional info)using NASM syntax (compatible with YASM in this case:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34190930/how-to-get-this-simple-assembly-to-run/34191324#34191324

Comment: `mmap(MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS)` is usually simpler in asm than adjusting the break for dynamic allocation.  You can `munmap` it in any order.