# macOS Ventura 13.1(22C65) cant run yasm excutable file

Tags: macos, assembly, yasm

asm file

```
section .data
    message db 'Hello, World!',0

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov eax, 4        ; write syscall number
    mov ebx, 1        ; stdout file descriptor
    mov ecx, qword [message]  ; address of message
    mov edx, 13       ; length of message
    int 0x80          ; invoke syscall

    mov eax, 1        ; exit syscall number
    xor ebx, ebx      ; exit status
    int 0x80          ; invoke syscall
```

command

1. `yasm -f macho64 hello.asm -o hello`
2. `chomd +x`
3. result `-bash: ./hello: cannot execute binary file`

I am using macOS m1 Ventura 13.1(22C65)

is there any solution

Comment: First of all, that source code is for 32-bit x86 Linux; no matter how you build it, it won't run on recent MacOS, which dropped support for 32-bit executables.  Second, YASM only assembles, to make a `.o`.  You forgot to link (with `gcc -nostdlib -static hello.o -o hello` if you were on Linux).

Comment: Also, that isn't the code you assembled; if you tried, it would reject `mov ecx, qword [message]` as an operand-size mismatch; you can't load 64 bits into a 32-bit register.  Maybe you meant `mov rcx, strict qword message` to use a 64-bit absolute address (instead of an efficient RIP-relative LEA), but `int 0x80` will ignore the high 32 bits even in 64-bit code.  [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730)

Comment: See [Hello World using x86 assembler on Mac 0SX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4288921) for x86-64 MacOS hello world.